# angularJs <ng-repeat> for loading a json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I tried to load a json file in my example-SPA app but for some motive i don't understand why when i try to run my application the controller don't fill my browser's tab...i'm a beginner and this is second day that i try to resolve this problem but my solution i think that givin out.
here my code :

```
<html ng-app="beerApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="js/libs/angular.js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="beerApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="beerCtrl">
    Search:<input ng-model="query" type="text"/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th><a>Name</a></th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'abv'">Abv</a></th>
        <th><a href="" ng-click="sortField = 'name'">Ibu</a></th>

      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="beer in beers | filter:query | orderBy:sortField">
        <td>{{beer.name}}</td>
        <td>{{beer.descript}}</td>
        <td>{{beer.abv}}</td>
        <td>{{beer.ibu}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

http://plnkr.co/edit/rBlt7tnCN8j0ys2HS7PZ?p=preview

thanks in advance
Albo
ps. Complete version is on plnkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an `index.html` tab in plnker. See the result [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3g6bYF916U6sqXzAMRxE?p=preview)

It is working as you expect it!

Comment: I did not know that! Kudos!